# Bash: Move multiple files with same name into same directory by renaming

Tags: bash

I currently have a bunch of .txt files in separate folders and want to move them all into the same folder, except all the files have the same name. I would like to preserve all the files by adding some sort of number so that each one isn't overwritten, like `FolderA/file.txt` becomes `NewFolder/file_1.txt`, and `FolderB/file.txt` becomes `NewFolder/file_2.txt`, etc. Is there a clean way to do this using bash? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: See if the `-b`/`--backup` options to `mv` do something useful for you.

Comment: Try `find /path -name file.txt -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} bash -c 'mv --backup=numbered "{}" /destination/$(basename "{}")'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this (either in a script or right on the command line):

```
for i in A B C D E  
do  
  mv Folder$i/file.txt NewFolder/file_$i.txt  
done
```

It won't convert letters to numbers, but it does the basics of what you're looking for in a fairly simple fashion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's close enough, I think I can live with letters instead of numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous answer, you can add two lines of code in bash to achieve your desired output:

```
declare -i n=1;
for i in A B C D E 
do
    mv Folder$i/file.txt NewFolder/file_$n.txt
    n+=1
done
```